# How to create a script in Linux to delete all files from the directory expect only left 5 files

Tags: linux, cron, conditional-statements

How to create a script in Linux to delete all files from the directory Condition:- If in the directory only 5 files are left then should not delete any files from that directory.

Comment: delete everything except a remainder of five files or delete all if more than five are found?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the number of files (files only excluding dirs and other thingss like or links) and not visiting sub directories can be get by :     find <mypathtodir>  -maxdepth 1  -type f | wc -l         to put it in a variable num=$( find <mypathtodir>  -maxdepth 1  -type f | wc -l)

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash

myPath="/tmp"

myFileList=$(find $myPath -maxdepth 1   -type f)

num=0

for candidate in $myFileList
do
        num=$(($num + 1))

        if [[ $num -le 5 ]]
        then
                echo "do not delete: $num"
                continue
        fi

        echo "number $num: delete $candidate"
        # remove the followong comment sign if you want the script to remove the file
        # rm $candidate
done
```

Comment: Hi tue,
Thanks for the script,

Comment: Hi Tue,

How do I edit this script for keep only latest 5 files?

Comment: change the line which generates the file list - use this:  myFileList=$(find $myPath -maxdepth 1   -type f  -printf "%C@ %p\n" |sort -rn |awk '1 {$1=""; print $0;}')

Comment: this adds a timestamp per file (-printf ...), sorts by time stamp first (sort -rn) -i.e. youngest first-  and then cuts off the time stamp from the start of a line (awk ...)

Comment: Hi Tue,
it's not working,
is there any other solution?

Comment: WHAT is not working?

Comment: I see the following. i mistake the change time and the midification time!! Change %C@ with %T@   Run this command:   find $myPath -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" |sort -rn;     and it shoiuld list your files with the youngest first

Comment: I created some files with backdating but those files are not getting deleted from the script

Comment: did you run the 'find' and check the files list? If the list is too long use find .....| more to get the output pagewise

Comment: may be there are spaces in filenames? The for-loop will become problems and handle each 'word' separate - see next answer

Answer (score 0):

to fix the problem with spaces in filenames change setting of 'IFS' shell variable before the for-loop:

```
#! /bin/bash

myPath="/tmp"

myFileList=$(find $myPath -maxdepth 1   -type f  -printf "%T@ %p\n" |sort -rn|awk '1 {$1=""; print $0;}')

num=0

OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

for candidate in $myFileList
do
        num=$(($num + 1))

        if [[ $num -le 5 ]]
        then
                echo "do not delete: $num  \"$candidate\""
                continue
        fi

        echo "number $num: delete $candidate"
        # remove the followong comment sign if you want the script to remove the file
        # rm $candidate
done
IFS="$OIFS"
```